# Fetching content from file and Ember CLI Mirage

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

I have a component in my Ember app which returns data from a static markdown file.

```js
  didInsertElement() {
    fetch('markdown/faqs-content.md').then(response => {
      response.text().then(result => {
        this.set('markdown', result);
      });
    });
  }
```

When the app runs, the request goes to `http://localhost:4200/markdown/faqs-content.md` and everything works fine.

However, in mirage, I get this error:

`Mirage: Your app tried to GET '/markdown/faqs-content.md', but there was no route defined to handle this request. Define a route for this endpoint in your routes() config. Did you forget to define a namespace?`

The above happens, even though the following is included in `mirage/config.js`:

`this.passthrough();`

Presumably, this is because the API namespace is not included in the request URL.

The problem can be solved by adding the full URL to passthrough:

`this.passthrough('https://localhost:4201/markdown/faqs-content.md');`

Doing this has two issues:

1. I don't always know the port that the app is served on, and
2. I don't want to lose the functionality of using `this.passThrough()`, which automatically invokes pass through for any API requests where there is no corresponding route in `mirage/config.js`.

I thus have 2 questions.

1. In `config.js`, is there any way of getting port that Ember server is running on, to allow something like `https://localhost:${port}/markdown/faqs-content.md`?
2. Is there a way that I can configure Mirage to pass through for the request to `https://localhost:4201/markdown/faqs-content.md`, and still allow it to pass through for any other requests that don't have a corresponding route defined?

Answer (score 1):

Passthrough (and the routing API in general) has some unfortunate strange behavior based on how it was coded + the underlying library it uses to intercept requests. We need to update the guides because others have run into this.

If you put

```js
this.namespace = 'api'
this.passthrough()
```

then Mirage will let all requests to `/api/*` passthrough, but if you move the call to `passthrough` before, *or* "reset" the namespace to the empty string, it should handle all requests to the current domain.

I'd need to test but I would try both

```js
this.namespace = ''
this.passthrough()
```

and

```js
this.passthrough('/**')
```

and see if they work. (We really need to add a nested routing DSL to Mirage! It would remove all these awkward APIs.)

Comment: Thank you. I've tried all of the approaches mentioned above, but unfortunately I still get the same error.

Comment: Reproduction on the miragejs issue would be the easiest way for me to diagnose!

Comment: Hi Sam, did you find  a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the second question, it seems that the following solves it:

```
  this.passthrough('https://localhost:4201/markdown/faqs-content.md');
  this.passthrough();
```